# Unificar linhas de um data frame

Tags: r

Ola, possuo um data frame com textos em suas linhas e preciso agrupar, um exemplo do data frame é:

```
df_inicial <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C", "B","A","A"), 
                             texto = c("Ola, estou bem", "Não", "Banana", "quero contato","abobora", "bom dia"))
```

preciso unir pelos grupos (id) e separado por espaço cada linha que foi unida, o resultado seria:

```
df_resultado <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                           texto = c("Ola, estou bem abobora bom dia", "Não quero contato", "Banana"))
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## R base

O seguinte `aggregate` resolve o problema numa linha.

```r
aggregate(texto ~ id, df_inicial, paste, collapse = " ")
#>   id                          texto
#> 1  A Ola, estou bem abobora bom dia
#> 2  B              Não quero contato
#> 3  C                         Banana
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Pacote `dplyr`

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

df_inicial %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(texto = paste(texto, collapse = " "))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   id    texto                         
#>   <chr> <chr>                         
#> 1 A     Ola, estou bem abobora bom dia
#> 2 B     Não quero contato             
#> 3 C     Banana
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>